# How set up stored procedure for output of list of items to SSRS report

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssrs-2008

I have a query that, in essence, goes through a list of tables (the list of which is pulled from a field in a table and stored in a cursor) to compare for invalid data and is supposed to return just the list of tables that have invalid data.

What I'm mainly struggling with is that I can't figure out how to properly set up the stored procedure to output the list in a way that SSRS can use. All I need in SSRS is the list of tables.

When I just run the SP, all of the queries' results are displayed in the SSMS Results grid - as would be expected, and in the Messages tab I do get the correct list of tables with invalid data.

In my research to figure out how to do this I can only find examples that return a single value. As I said, I need to return a list of values.

Here is my stored procedure (the commented code is an attempt to store the list of tables into a temporary table for SSRS to grab the list from):

```
USE MasterFiles
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('sp_GetInvalidXrefCategories') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE sp_GetInvalidXrefCategories
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetInvalidXrefCategories

@includeAR bit,
@includeClin bit,
@includePayroll bit,
@includeGL bit,
@includeAP bit,
@includeDeletes bit

AS


-- Get the list of xref categories
DECLARE @listOfCategories TABLE
    ( CategoryName varchar(100) )
INSERT INTO @listOfCategories (CategoryName)
SELECT Category FROM MasterFiles..Categories
WHERE Category IN (SELECT Category FROM MasterFiles..xref) AND TableToValidate = 'xref'
ORDER BY Category

-- Store the list of categories so we can loop through them
DECLARE categoryList CURSOR FOR
SELECT CategoryName FROM @listOfCategories

DECLARE @validationCategory nvarchar(100)

-- To store the list of invalid categories for later output
DECLARE @listOfInvalidCategories TABLE
    ( CategoryName varchar(100) )

--CREATE TABLE #tmpInvalidCatsList ( catName varchar(100) )
--DECLARE @Output varchar(max)

OPEN categoryList
FETCH NEXT FROM categoryList INTO @validationCategory

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MasterFiles..xref WHERE category = @validationCategory) = 0 OR (@validationCategory = 'Employee_No' OR @validationCategory = 'County'))
            FETCH NEXT FROM categoryList INTO @validationCategory
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @validationTable nvarchar(100)
                DECLARE @validationField nvarchar(100)
                DECLARE @validationQuery nvarchar(max)

                SET @validationTable = (SELECT ValidationTable FROM MasterFiles..Categories WHERE Category = @validationCategory AND TableToValidate = 'xref')
                SET @validationField = (SELECT ValidationField FROM MasterFiles..Categories WHERE Category = @validationCategory AND TableToValidate = 'xref')

                --PRINT 'Validating category ' + @validationCategory + ' against Angus table ' + @validationTable

                IF @validationCategory = 'action_code'
                     -- Action_Code needs Action_Type and Action_Code concatenated to compare Angus table to xref
                    BEGIN
                        IF @includeDeletes = 0
                            BEGIN
                                SET @validationQuery = N'SELECT DISTINCT category FROM MasterFiles..xref WHERE Category = ''validationCategory'' AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT Action_Type + '' '' + ValidationField FROM Angus..validationTable) AND new_value != ''DELETE'' OR new_value IS NULL OR new_value = '''')'
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                SET @validationQuery = N'SELECT DISTINCT category FROM MasterFiles..xref WHERE Category = ''validationCategory'' AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT Action_Type + '' '' + ValidationField FROM Angus..validationTable) OR new_value IS NULL OR new_value = '''')'
                            END
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        IF @includeDeletes = 0
                            BEGIN
                                SET @validationQuery = N'SELECT DISTINCT category FROM MasterFiles..xref WHERE Category = ''validationCategory'' AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT ValidationField FROM Angus..validationTable) AND new_value != ''DELETE'' OR new_value IS NULL OR new_value = '''')'
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                SET @validationQuery = N'SELECT DISTINCT category FROM MasterFiles..xref WHERE Category = ''validationCategory'' AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT ValidationField FROM Angus..validationTable) OR new_value IS NULL OR new_value = '''')'
                            END
                    END

                SET @validationQuery = REPLACE(@validationQuery,'validationCategory',@validationCategory)
                SET @validationQuery = REPLACE(@validationQuery,'validationField',@validationField)
                SET @validationQuery = REPLACE(@validationQuery,'validationTable',@validationTable)

                --PRINT @validationQuery
                DECLARE @rowCount int

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @validationQuery

                SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

                IF @rowCount > 0
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO @listOfInvalidCategories (CategoryName)
                        SELECT @validationCategory
                        --INSERT INTO #tmpInvalidCatsList
                        --SELECT @validationCategory
                    END


                FETCH NEXT FROM categoryList INTO @validationCategory
            END
    END

-- OUTPUT THE LIST OF INVALID CATEGORIES
DECLARE @invalidCategory nvarchar(100)
DECLARE invalidCategoryList CURSOR FOR
SELECT CategoryName FROM @listOfInvalidCategories

OPEN invalidCategoryList
FETCH NEXT FROM invalidCategoryList INTO @invalidCategory

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @invalidCategory
        FETCH NEXT FROM invalidCategoryList INTO @invalidCategory
    END

--SELECT @Output as [Output]
--FROM #tmpInvalidCatsList

--RETURN @Output

CLOSE categoryList
DEALLOCATE categoryList

CLOSE invalidCategoryList
DEALLOCATE invalidCategoryList
```

Comment: Don't use `PRINT` to return data to SSRS, use `SELECT`. For example if you put `SELECT * FROM @listOfCategories` at the end of your proc you'd get a recordset that SSRS can use.

Comment: Thanks, Nick - I had the prints in there for when I was checking output while building/testing the routine. The commented code for temp table `#tmpInvalidCatsList` is intended to hold the list of tables and as you can see there's a select near the end of the procedure. I am getting the list of tables when I execute the SP in SSMS, so I'm guessing that's what SSRS will "see" and be able to use as output?

Comment: Yes. Don't `RETURN` it though, just select it. There is (no joke) 5 different ways that I can think of that you can return data from a SP. The one SSRS likes is a SELECT statement. Don't use `RETURN` though. When you try it what happens?

Comment: In the Messages tab I get the list of tables that I was expecting. I'll have to wait for my co-worker to plug the SP into an SSRS report, though to see how that likes it, but from what you're saying it sounds like it should work...

Comment: No. You need the data to appear in the Results tab. `select 'this works' as AColumn print 'this wont'`
`